# Is there a method to get role colours on discord embeds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am new to creating discord bots.
I want to make a color selection but when I type @red or something the @red has no color and it is not red.

Here is my code:

```js
case 'embed':
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('So... you joined this server... now pick a colour. ')
      .addField('Austarataboo', message.author.username)
      .setDescription('@red \n \n@Orange \n \n@Yellow \n \n@Pink \n \n@lavender blush \n \nPurple \n \n@Dark blue \n \n@Blue \n \n@Peach \n \n@Lime \n \n@Black \n \n@Sea')
      .setColor(message.member.displayHexColor)
      .setFooter('i have spent 2 days trying to make a embed pls send dino nuggies, also thanks to @Welcome to the dark side@ for the rules')
  message.channel.send(embed);
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you simply type "@red" or "@Orange", it is treated as literal text, **so you need to instead reference the IDs of the roles**.

You can get the ID of a role by doing the following:

1. Enable Developer Mode in Discord
   [image: Developer Mode in Discord settings]
2. Right-click the role you want the ID of in the profile of a user who has it and click "Copy ID".
   [image: Copy ID option on right-click of role]

Once you have the ID of a role, you should type `<@&ROLE_ID>` in the embed description instead, e.g.

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('test')
        .addField('foo', message.author.username)
        .setDescription('<@&123456> hello!')
        .setColor(message.member.displayHexColor)
        .setFooter('bar')
```

if the role's ID was `123456`.

[See here for ways to embed other mention types](https://docs.discord.club/embedg/reference/mentions).